# redirecting python output to a log file

Tags: python, variables, output

I have a simple request. I have a python file with a list of variables.  I want to execute the python file and get the output of that written to the log file. What is the simple way to do this?
Example:
var.py has the following code

```
x = (10,11,12)
y = str("case when id =1 then gr8 else ok end")
z = datetime.datatime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

I want the log to show the variables resolution in the same order

```
x = (10,11,12)
y = 'case when id =1 then gr8 else ok end'
z = 2016-06-07
```

How can I accomplish this in python?

This is what  I tried

```
# In:
import logging

# set root logger level
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# setup custom logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.FileHandler('example.log')
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)

# log
x = (10,11,12)
y = str("case when id =1 then gr8 else ok end")
logger.debug(x)
logger.debug(y)
```

example.log file is empty

Comment: There isn't a clear-cut way to do that, but you can jerry-rig something using Python's built-in log module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Input/Output Operations](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm) with Python is easy.

You can open, write and close a file manually, ie.:

```
text_file = open("OutputFile.txt", "w")
text_file.write("Write blablabla into a file")
text_file.close()
```

Or you use a context manager (the file is closed automatically for you), ie.:

*This is generally a better coding practice..*

```
with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write("Write blablabla into a file")
```

In your example:

```
import datetime

x = (10,11,12)
y = str("case when id =1 then gr8 else ok end")
z = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

outfile = 'outputfile.txt'

with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(x))
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(y)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(z)
    f.write("\n")
```

Produces a file called `outputfile.txt` in the script folder, with the following lines:

```
(10, 11, 12)
case when id =1 then gr8 else ok end
2016-06-07
```

But if you want a logging specific library, you can take a look at [`LOGGING`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html).

```
import datetime, logging

logfile = 'logfile.log'

logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile, 
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

x = (10,11,12)
y = str("case when id =1 then gr8 else ok end")
z = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

logging.info(x)
logging.info(y)
logging.info(z)
```

This will produce the following output:

```
2016-06-07 15:28:12.874 INFO (10, 11, 12)
2016-06-07 15:28:12.874 INFO case when id =1 then gr8 else ok end
2016-06-07 15:28:12.874 INFO 2016-06-07
```

Comment: tried this code in IPython. I do not see the log file.log file in my python folder? Is there any specific addition like handlers I need to add to make the log file ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the python logger functionality

> ```
> import logging
> logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
> x = (10,11,12)
> y = str("case when id =1 then gr8 else ok end")
> logging.debug(x)
> logging.debug(y)
> ```

Comment: I want the output to include the variable name as well . example z=2016-06-07

Comment: Manipulate the object . Pretend the string before the string object.

Comment: logging.debug("x=" + str(x))

Comment: I tried the following code. But  I see the example.log is empty

Comment: I do not understand the logging model completely. But what  I see is that when I execute from my IPython note book, I see  the log file in the folder but it is empty. I see the logger object is created, but not sure about the actual log file. Can you try this in IPython?